# Read XLSX to from the update query

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using XLSX NPM to read the XLSX file and i converted to json as like below

My Xlsx sheet is of format:..

```
skill  id     name              xx
abc    4578   express-basic     30
       4698   express-advanced   60
qwerty 7856   express-basic      90

MY Json:

[ { skill: 'abc',
    id: 4578,
    name: 'express-basic',
    xx: 30 },
  { id: 4689, name: 'express-advanced', xx: 60 },
  { skill: 'qwerty',
    id: 7856,
     name: 'express-advanced',
    xx: 90 } ]
```

I have to update `collection X where id=4578,4689 ass skill = abc` so how can i convert the below json into as follows:

```
[
{'abc':[4578,4689]},
{'qwerty':[7856]}
]
```

so that i can loop through this and i can update the collectionX. My problem is how can i know the next skill is starting from the json and construct the Above array. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You Can work with `array.reduce`.

```
YOUR_JSON_ARRAY.reduce(function (obj, item) {
    obj[item.skill] = obj[item.skill] || [];
    obj[item.skill].push(item.id);
    return obj;
}, {});
```

Above code will `groupBy` your Array by using `item.skill` key.

P.S. you need to handle this if `item.skill` doesn't exists,
otherwise it will create `undefined` key:value pair.

Hope it will help.